Send CSV File to Box Folder Using KingswaySoft Box Destination
I'm trying to automate the process of sending a csv to a Box folder from withing Visual Studio 2019 using the KingswaySoft Box Destination component. My Box connection manager connects successfully. Do I need to convert my CSV file to another format (image) and extract file details from it to map to the fields in the Box Destination Editor?
I wasn't expecting this would be part of a dataflow. I expected it to be more comparable to an email component where you just attach the file to an email in the main flow section and it get where it needs to go. I'm stuck at the Destination Editor.

You could use a Premium File System Source component to read the CSV file and get the FileContent field, which is the binary data. However, an easier way would be to use our Premium File Transfer Task in the control flow. In this case, you can choose the Source Path to pick the CSV file, choose the Box Connection Manager as your Destination connection, and set the path. You can find more details in our Online Help Manual for the task here. If you have any further questions, please feel free to reach out to our Solutions and Support team at https://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us
